# Substring String until first letter

Tags: java, regex, substring

I need to `substring` the String (user input) until first letter. I cannot use regex in `indexOf`. I tried like this:

`String stringValue = input.substring(0, input.indexOf([^\\d.]));`

Comment: Something like this? `^\W*` pattern - start of the string `^` followed by zero or more *non-letters*?

Comment: Can you add few examples.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko it returns `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know for certain your string starts with numbers, you can simply split it:

```
String input = "1234x";
System.out.println(input.split("[^\\d.]")[0]); //1234
```

Note that if it didn't start with numbers, first indexes will be empty for each character which doesn't conform to \d.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a straightforward solution, but this could work :

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "1248941e189d1";
    int index = -1, i = 0;

    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(s.substring(0, index));
  }
```

You first look for the first letter in the string, then you simply take the substring until its index.

Answer (score 1):

Find the first letter in a `String` using regular expression; nothing too fancy, no *tricks*:

```
private static final Pattern LETTER = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");  
        // or "\\p{Alpha}", or "\\p{L}", or whatever is needed

// inentionally throws NullPointerException if argument is null
public static int findFirstLetter(String text) {
    var matcher = LETTER.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.start();
    } else {
        return -1;  // or throw exception, or ...
    }
}
```

I prefer this since it does exactly what I want (I do not want to `split` or `replace` anything, just `find`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want what is before the first occurrence of a letter, you could use a capturing group to match any char except a letter using `\P{L}` and then match a letter using `\p{L}`.

```
^(\P{L}+)\p{L}
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\P{L}+` Match 1+ times the opposite of `\p{L}`
- `)`
- `\p{L}` Match any letter from any language

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpvJTG/1) | [Java demo](http://ideone.com/m5tLyw)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\P{L}+)\\p{L}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("1234x");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
1234
```

Answer (score -2):

This might work for you:

```
jshell> s
s ==> " 123abc"

jshell> s.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]{1}.*", "")
$6 ==> " 123"
```

Here we are matching a letter followed by any character and replacing the match with empty string.

Comment: Cant use this thing, because user can input "123abc123".

Comment: What do you want in this case "123abc123"? If you want both numbers you can use 'split' method.

Comment: need only first 123